# THREE.PointLight

Tags: three.js

I create a THREE.PlaneGeometry with heights, in the highest point locate a THREE.PointLight, but this illuminates areas that are not seen from this point.
Why?
I want light from a point only the areas that are viewed from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the appearance of any given point on a surface is calculated using the lights, their properties and of course the material properties - it does not take the rest of the scene into account, as that would be very computationally expensive. Various ray tracing renderers do this, but they are really slow, and that's not how WebGL and Three.js work.

What you want is shadows. Three.js is capable of rendering shadows using Shadow Map method. There are various examples on using shadow maps both on the net and Three.js examples folder.

A word of warning though, getting shadows to work well can be hard if you don't have the basics down well - you may need to do some studying. Shadows can slow your application down (specially with many lighs) and look ugly if not properly configured and fine-tuned. Also I think shadow maps are only supported for SpotLight and DirectionalLight, PointLights are trickier.